# Excel Time Subtraction

Tags: excel, time

I need to subtract the difference between two times in excel, but When I subtract time from one column to the other, the output is displayed as #####.
I have formatted the cells containing the time as hh:mm:ss and the result as hh:mm. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`#####` is displayed if the cell content doesn't fit cell width. You need to increase the column width.

Comment: please edit your comment and post the values and formula you used., so we can reproduce exactly the problem that you have.

Comment: Also check that the difference in times is not negative

Comment: Yes actually the time I was putting was the main problem. When I checked subtracting the other way round, it gave me the perfect answer, but that was not what I had wanted.
I was trying to subtract 4:30 PM from 12:00 AM from the next day, but I did not put the dates for these values. So I guess that's the reason I was getting this output.
After I concatenated the time and date and then tried to subtract, it worked fine.
Thanks for all your help. :)